# What does the keyword 'w/' mean?

Tags: abbreviations

I read about VM in MIT OCW 6.828 (the lecture at https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-828-operating-system-engineering-fall-2012/lecture-notes-and-readings/MIT6_828F12_lec4_notes.pdf), but I didn't understand what was meant by the following phrase:

> mark PTE as valid w/ PTE_P

What the heck is 'w/'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`w/` is an abbreviation for the English word "with". To my knowledge, it carries no specific meaning for Operating Systems.